# How to customize outlined button using MDCButtons in Swift?

Tags: swift, material-design

I'm customizing my `UIButton` using `MDCButton`. I want to make my button outlined and customize its color.

In this case, I'm using `MDCOutlinedButtonThemer`. 
I also implement `MDCButton` (`MDCButtonColorThemer`) with custom color in other button and it working.
I've tried to set my button with default `MDCOutlinedButton` and it works.

This is my code :

```
MDCOutlinedButtonThemer.applyScheme(buttonScheme, to: self.btnAddToCart)

MDCButtonColorThemer.applySemanticColorScheme(ApplicationScheme.shared.colorScheme, to: self.btnBuy)
```

This is the ApplicationScheme.swift :

```
public let colorScheme: MDCColorScheming = { 
    let scheme = MDCSemanticColorScheme(defaults: .material201804)
    //TODO: Customize our app Colors after this line
    scheme.primaryColor = UIColor(red: 255.0 / 255.0, green: 201.0 / 255.0, blue: 46.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1)
    //scheme.primaryColorVariant = UIColor(red: 68.0/255.0, green: 44.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    //scheme.onPrimaryColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    scheme.secondaryColor = UIColor(red: 254.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    //scheme.onSecondaryColor = UIColor(red: 68.0/255.0, green: 44.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    scheme.surfaceColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    //scheme.onSurfaceColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    scheme.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    //scheme.onBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 68.0/255.0, green: 44.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    //scheme.errorColor = UIColor(red: 197.0/255.0, green: 3.0/255.0, blue: 43.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    return scheme
}()
```

[image]

I want to make "Add to cart" button's border color same with "buy" button's color

Answer (score 4):

You can use next color settings for creation MDCButton:

```
let myButton = MDCButton()

myButton.setTitle("Add to cart", for: .normal)
myButton.isUppercaseTitle = false
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 150, height: 40)
myButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.white)
myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControl.State.normal)
myButton.setBorderColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControl.State.normal)
myButton.setBorderWidth(1.0, for: UIControl.State.normal)
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

view.addSubview(myButton)
```